# Is $(L_1L_2)^* \subset L_1^*L_2^*$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, formal-languages

Is $(L_1L_2)^* \subset L_1^*L_2^*$ ?

I tried with simple languages, 
$L_1 = \{0\}$ 
$L_1^* = \{\epsilon, 0, 00, 000, \ldots\}$

$L_2 = \{ab, ba\}$ 
$L_2^* = \{\epsilon, ab, ba, abab, baba, abba, baab, \ldots\}$

$L_1L_2 = \{0ab, 0ba\}$ 
$(L_1L_2)^* = \{\epsilon, 0ab, 0ba, 0ab0ab, 0ba0ba, \ldots\}$ 
$L_1^*L_2^* = \{\epsilon, 0ab, 0ba, 00ab, 000baab, \ldots\}$

So then $(L_1L_2)^* \subset L_1^*L_2^*$, because it doesn't contain strings that begin with more than one $0$.

What about $L_1^* \cap L_2^*$ and $(L_1 \cap L_2)^*$? 
I arrived to the answer that $(L_1 \cap L_2)^* \subset L_1^* \cap L_2^*$

---

**Edit**: I see where I went wrong for the first pair, and I understand that my example doesn't show that the $LHS$ is a subset of the $RHS$. Is there any language $L_1$ that is a subset of another language $L_2$, other than $L_1 = L_2$?

Comment: You can write braces $\{\ \}$ in MathJax by `\{` and `\}` respectively. For further information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(L_1 L_2)^* \nsubseteq L_1^* L_2^*$ in general. Take $L_1 = \{a\}, \ L_2 = \{b\}$.  The $LHS$ contains strings that look like $ababab...ab$, while the $RHS$ only contains strings of the form $aaaaabbbbb$.

Comment: Oh I see what I did wrong. The question says to state if one of them is a subset of the other, or if they are equal to each other. If they arent subsets of one another then they are never equal,, so does it depend on the languages $L_1$ and $L_2$.

Comment: Yep.  But I don't know how it depends on them.  I.e. I don't know of a statement of the form $A \subset B$ iff certain properties of langages $A$ and $B$ hold.